# Ajax send hebrew chars to server

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, model-view-controller, jersey

Im trying to send hebrew chars in ajax request,
This is the server side code:

```
@POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA+ ";charset=utf-8")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8" })
    public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader,@Context UriInfo info) {some code....}
```

this function get `inputStream` object- some file to upload, and `FormDataContentDisposition` -object that contain file name inside,

My problem is that when the file name writen in hebrew the function get it in gibberish chars,
(this function `@consumes` contain `utf-8` but its not working).

Here is my ajax request code:

```
 var fd = new FormData();
         fd.append('file', files[i].file);
         fd.append('title', "תמונה.jpg");
     $.ajax({
             //loading progress
             beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#loader').addClass('overlay');
                },
              complete: function(){
                    $('#loader').removeClass('overlay');
                  },

             type: 'POST',
             url: global.rootURL + 'documents/upload/' + "?rashutId=" + '140' + "&propertyId=" + propertyId+ "&title=" + titles[i]+"&taskId="+imageTaskId+"&imageId="+imageId+"&draftInd="+draftInd+"&isDeleted="+isDeleted,
             data: fd,
            async:false,
             processData: false,
            contentType: false,
             dataType: 'text',
             success: function(data, status) {


             },
             error: function(data, status) {

                 flag=false;


             }
         });
```

I have tried to change contentType param to "charset: utf-8" but its not working I got error from server (error code 415).

Someone have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: You're mixing Spring and Jersey liberally. Pick a single framework. Note that despite the tag, it *looks* mostly Jerseyish. In either case, you almost certainly have server logs.

Comment: I'll change it Thanks.